Redirect unmatched subdomains to a specific URL
I have a website running on Google App Engine.  I want a particular subdomain (e.g. portal.example.com) to map to my website.  All others I want to map to a marketing page on another website (e.g. www.example.com, example.com, and foo.example.com should all redirect to mycompany.com/product.html).
Currently, I have A records pointing from portal.example.com, example.com, and www.example.com to the IP address of a Google Cloud load balancer.  The load balancer matching rules redirect any request that don't match portal.example.com to the marketing page.
This works for example.com and www.example.com.  If I create a  wildcard CNAME record to redirect all other subdomains domains to my load balancer also, though, clients will get a security warning for incorrect certificates, because the SSL certificate for the load balancer was created just for example.com and www.example.com.  I tried creating one for *.example.com, but Google Cloud won't let me create a wildcard SSL certificate for a load balancer, as far as I can tell.
Is what I want to do possible in Google Cloud?
